# Recursive type-declaration in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've tried this every which way I can think of, and I did look at other similar posts regarding recursive types, but I haven't been able to create a type that works recursively for this case.

What I want is for this type to accept partial properties of `CSSStyleDeclaration`, and, for any properties *not* matching a property of `CSSStyleDeclaration`, I want it to map back to the type itself.

This seems to work only for the first level:

```
interface NestedCSSDeclarations {
    [name: string]: CSSDeclaration;
}

type CSSDeclaration = {
    [P in keyof CSSStyleDeclaration]?: CSSStyleDeclaration[P];
} & NestedCSSDeclarations

function css(obj: CSSDeclaration) {
    // ...
}

let style = {
  headline: css({
    color: "red",
    h1: {
      color: "blue",
      "&:hover": {
        color: "green"
      }
    },
    "@media screen and (min-width: 400px)": {
      h1: {
        fontSize: "50px"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Is there no way to type-hint this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `|` operator instead of `&` it will work fine

```
type CSSDeclaration = {
    [P in keyof CSSStyleDeclaration]?: CSSStyleDeclaration[P];
} | NestedCSSDeclarations
```

Comment: It appears you're right, but... this doesn't mesh with my understanding of the `|` and `&` type-operators. Normally I use the `|` operator for type alternatives, e.g. `number | string` which means it's either and can't be both. I thought the `&` operator was for combined types, e.g. `Foo & Bar` means it has to be both. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: Because it can't be both at the same time in your case, nested CSS identifier like `&:hover` isn't the same as a CSS property like `color`